# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects but I can run it fine through my own IDLE?

Tags: python

I'm running on Python 2.7.10 with the following code:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input:
    test_cases = input.read().strip().splitlines()

for test in test_cases:
    orig_number = test
    iteration = 0
    while True:
        if str(orig_number) == str(orig_number)[::-1]:
            print iteration, orig_number
            break
        iteration += 1
        orig_number = orig_number + int(str(orig_number)[::-1])
```

And it will run without a hitch but running it on Code Eval on Python 2.7.3 It keeps returning a

```
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

On the last line but I can't figure out why it's returning that as both parts seem to be an int.

Comment: It's hard to know what you're trying to do since you didn't provide any sample input, but `orig_number` is a string. Note that because it's a string `str(orig_number)` just returns `orig_number`.

Comment: Sorry, It's a multiple line put of a number on each line, that must be reversed then added with itself until the number is a palindrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure where this is working, but clearly `orig_number` is not an `int` . When you read stuff from a file , and then do `strip()` / `splitlines()` on it, you get back a list of strings.

Hence, in the `for` loop, `test` is a string, and hence `orig_number` is also a string.

You do not need to convert them to `str` explicitly and you should convert the `orig_number` to `int` before trying to add, and then convert them back to `str` to save in `orig_number`. Example:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input:
    test_cases = input.read().strip().splitlines()

for orig_number in test_cases:
    iteration = 0
    while True:
        if orig_number == orig_number[::-1]:
            print iteration, orig_number
            break
        iteration += 1
        orig_number = str(int(orig_number) + int(orig_number[::-1]))
```

Comment: Simple answer and it worked perfectly for what I needed.  I keep making the assumption if the input is a number it's already an int no matter how I change it and I need to work away from that.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over `test_cases` which contains strings so first of all you don't need to convert it to string with `str` and you need to convert it to `int` as the end of code.

Also instead of reading and stripping and then using `splitline` you can simply as a more pythonic way just loop over your file object :

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input:
     for test in input:
            orig_number = test.strip()
            iteration = 0
            while True:
                if orig_number == orig_number[::-1]:
                    print iteration, orig_number
                    break
                iteration += 1
                orig_number = int(orig_number) + int(orig_number[::-1])
```

Also note that since converting the `string` to `int` may raise an exception you can handle such problems with a `try-except` statement.

```
try:
    orig_number = int(orig_number) + int(orig_number[::-1])
except ValueError:
    # raise exception or do stuff
```

Comment: This returned a new error on line 8 with the check for the number and it reversed saying int has no attribute __getitem__ but otherwise I have never thought of doing the stripping separately. Which I will definitely start implementing